# How to switch off discrete graphics card?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I've got one big problem that I simply can't solve. I got a HP Pavilion dv6 Laptop and it runs Linux Mint Debian Edition. This Laptop runs a hybrid graphics system and I want to switch off the discrete card as it is an AMD Radeon and it simply does not work very well with Linux - it overheats to about 90°Celcius but is not used at all by the OS.
I tried `echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` with proper file permissions and I went trough a few tutorials witch told me the exact same thing. The only problem is that the turorials worked and by machine goes to some kind of shell prompt after I ran the command. It shows any kinds of system messages and stuff and fan speed increases but the whole desktop environment crashes and the system won't even allow me to switch to command line mode and log in. It shows system messages, freezes and tries to cool down (which I think means that the discrete card is switched off).

I would be very thankful for your help because I'm trying to fix this problem for a few weeks now.
Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can try https://github.com/sangshuduo/discrete-graphic-disabler to see if it work on your computer.

Comment: ok, I really appreciate your help, but I do not know what to do with this code…

Comment: It's a kernel module. You need download the entity source code of the kernel you are using. Then you need compile the discrete-graphic-disabler module with specified kernel source path. After that, you can use 'insmod discrete-graphic-disabler.ko' to disable and use 'rmmod discrete-graphic-disabler' to turn it on.

Comment: ok, I compiled and installed the module and it is loaded automatically by the kernel but the discrete card is still powered and heats up to 80°...so nothing changed...

Comment: could you let me know what model your radeon graphic card is?

Comment: `$ lspci | grep "VGA"
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Caicos [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try another github project https://github.com/mkottman/acpi_call and it has an example shell script turn_off_gpu.sh

Comment: thank you very much, this works pretty fine, not as fine as possible, but pretty fine…

Comment: ok, I tried it again without my external display connected and the whole UI froze and I wasn't even able to switch to command line mode…